# BluetoothSocket - connection timeout

Tags: android, bluetooth

It's there any way to set connection timeout to BluetoothSocket?

If my device is offline, connection process takes a few seconds and then returns an error. I need to set the timeout to 1 second. It is possible?

```
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(APP_UUID);
// socket.setProxyConnectionTimeout(1000); <- some like this
socket.connect();
```

BluetoothSocket class have PROXY_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, but never used...
Thanks for answers.

BTW:

I try some like this:

```
socket.connect();
Thread.sleep(1000);
socket.close(); // but socket is not closed & still connecting
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't change timeout of BluetoothSocket.connect(). As documentation:

***This method will block until a connection is made or the connection fails. If this method returns without an exception then this socket is now connected.***
A workaround.

Ex: timeout 5s. Using CountDownTimer to check if connect is complete(success or fail). After 5s, if connection is incomplete then use BluetoothSocket.close() to cancel.

As BluetoothSocket documentation:

***close() can be used to abort this call from another thread.***

Answer (score 0):

Ok this code is only slightly tested but it works so far:

```
Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            socket = pairedBTDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.FromString(uuid));
            socket.ConnectAsync();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (socket.IsConnected)
            {
                // call a function here
                // my function blocks for the application lifetime
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                socket.Close();
            }
        }

    });
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

socket.connect();
This method will block until a connection is made or the connection
so.if connect could not establish.
Thread.sleep(1000);
Would not excute.
Or other method behind socket.connect();  would not execte too.